# Best place to install Jython on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard, jython

I'm trying to install Jython on my Mac (Snow Leopard).  The installer prompts me to install it under

```
/Users/myusername/jython2.5.2
```

However this seems to be an inappropriate place to install an interpreter core, library modules etc...

Any suggestions as to where might be a more appropriate folder...  What about

```
/User/bin/jython2.5.2
```

Would there be any side-effects of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with `/usr/local/bin`, as that is the standard directory for user-installed binaries in the rest of the *nix world. Plus, it's already in your `PATH`. Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) helps managing these things.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Homebrew too.  Sounds good. Prembo.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) you don't have to worry about these things.

```
brew install jython
```